# Can I use RSpec's #scenario with Rails system tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-6

I wanted to use `scenario` with Rails builtin system tests. Since Rails system and RSpec feature tests are almost identical, I expected it to work interchangeably, but instead I got:

`undefined method 'scenario' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::Authentication:Class`.

Am I missing something or is this not possible currently?

Answer (score 0):

`scenario` is a method of gem Capybara. Rspec equivalent to scenario is `it`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scenario` in your RSpec tests. But it is Capybara's method. So you need to load this gem first.

For this purpose you need to add to your `Gemfile`

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

And after this

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: I already have it loaded and configured. Scenario is possible to use with feature tests, as [per documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec), but there's no reason to use those having system tests in place. Hence, my question :)

Comment: @sloneorzeszki I tried to replace `it` to `scenario` in my non-feature tests. And it works perfectly

Comment: By non-feature do you mean system tests?

Comment: Model tests, view tests, controller tests